# Will Foo(Foo x){ } ever be called in C++?

Tags: c++

I have an query regarding C++ syntax/construct : in what scenario can the following Foo(Foo x){} be called?
I understand that it wont be called for initialization like, as they will call copy constructor

```
Foo a;
Foo x = a;
or 
Foo x(a);
```

Not for the conversion of type as the argument passed to it is of same type as class

Can't think of scenario on which Foo(Foo x){} be called, or it will be always a dead code.

```
class Foo { 
  public :
    Foo(Foo x){  // notice it is not not a Copy constructor!!, i intented it to make like ordinary ctor taking same class object
    }
    Foo(int x) : m_data(x){}
private :
  int m_data;
};
```

Comment: And if the compiler allowed it, it would stackoverflow.

Comment: `error C2652: 'Foo' : illegal copy constructor: first parameter must not be a 'Foo'`

Comment: @Mysticial is correct , it would result in infinite recursion and  stakcoverflow , if compiler allowed it.

Comment: @Anand its more important to hear what standard says rather than what compiler does. Answer below by Spook is more complete

Comment: @David agreed , but its interesting to speculate too ;-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have you actually tried to compile this code?

```
Error   1   error C2652: 'Foo' : illegal copy constructor: first parameter must not be a 'Foo'  main.cpp    5   1   NativeConsoleSketchbook
```

#### C++11 standard, 12.8.6:

> A declaration of a constructor for a class X is ill-formed if its first parameter is of type (optionally cv-qualified)
>   X and either there are no other parameters or else all other parameters have default arguments.

Comment: I think it's because error message should be a comment, not an answer.  However, after quote was added, the answer is well-formed, I think. Compensated.

Comment: @soon Even if there was no quote about C++ std, why should it be a comment? It actually *answers* the question, doesn't it?

Comment: @Spook: Some people just itch to downvote short answers. +1 from me.

Comment: I don't think so. Even if error message _can_ help to find a mistake, but only the Standard can give a guarantee that this **is** mistake.

Comment: @soon OK, fair enough.

Comment: Thanks @Spook to figuring it out.I was trying to find the exact cause of the Error. Now the standard clearly state that.

Answer (score 3):

Quoting from [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_constructor) Wikipedia article(emphasis mine):

> The following are **invalid copy constructors** (Reason - **copy_from_me is
>   not passed as reference**) :
>
> X(X copy_from_me);
>   X(const X copy_from_me);
>
> because the call to those constructors would require a copy as well,
>   which would result in an **infinitely recursive call**.

Answer (score 2):

`Foo(Foo x)` will never be called since the code will try to interpret it as a copy constructor and fail at it (compile error).

Non-type methods (such as constructors, destructors etc.) should follow the syntax for each case.